# Разбор предложения

Tags: члены-предложения

Какое предложение осложненное?Чем?

Под осенними лучами солнца тихо дремлет увядающая природа.

Сухой иней с мягким шелестом полился с потревоженных ветвей.

Заунывный ветер гонит стаю туч на край неба.

Зной и степная скука утомили Егорушку.

При первом взгляде на своих Егорушка почувствовал непреодолимую потребность жаловаться.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере - это предложение 4. Оно осложнено однородными членами предложения: Зной и степная скука.

Comment: Я думала-зной и степная скука-не выступают как единое подлежащее т.е. как синтаксически цельное словосочетание?

Comment: Так и есть. Это не цельное синтаксически цельное словосочетание. Имеется в виду и зной, и степная скука. А о едином подлежащем можете прочитать здесь:[Подлежащее, способы его выражения](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#311)